# How to clear same multiple columns on different sheets in worksheet in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a Google sheet workbook with 4 sheets. Each sheet will need the following columns to be cleared each Friday (columns C3:S40 and column U3:U40). Here is what I came up with but it doesn't work all the way through. So I was wondering if anyone can help me to simplify the script. Thank you in advance!

```
function ClearCells()
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetbyName ();
sheet.getRange(C3:S40).clearContent();
sheet.getRange(U3:U40).clearContent();}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function ClearRangesofSelectedSheets() {
  const shts = ["Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3"];
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  shts.forEach(name => {
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
    sheet.getRange("C3:S40").clearContent();
    sheet.getRange("U3:U40").clearContent();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to simplify your showing script.
- As the additional function, you want to use your script for the specific 4 sheets in a Google Spreadsheet.

#### Modification points:

- It seems that your function of `function ClearCells()` is not enclosed by `{}`.
- `getSheetbyName ()` of `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetbyName ()` is required to be `getSheetByName("Sheet name")`.
- When `getRange` method of Class Sheet is used, `C3:S40` and `U3:U40` of `sheet.getRange(C3:S40).clearContent()` and `sheet.getRange(U3:U40).clearContent()` are required to be given as the string value as follows.

  ```
    sheet.getRange("C3:S40").clearContent();
    sheet.getRange("U3:U40").clearContent();
  ```
- In your script, `sheet.getRange("C3:S40").clearContent()` and `sheet.getRange("U3:U40").clearContent()` can be modified by one call as follows.

  ```
    sheet.getRangeList(["C3:S40", "U3:U40"]).clearContent();
  ```
- In order to use your script to the specific 4 sheets, it is required to give the sheets.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function ClearCells() {
  var sheetNames = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2",,,]; // Please set the sheet names you want to use.

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  sheetNames.forEach(sheetName =>
    sheet.getSheetByName(sheetName).getRangeList(["C3:S40", "U3:U40"]).clearContent()
  );
}
```

Or, in order to simplify the script, you can also use the following script. When you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function ClearCells() {
  var sheetNames = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2",,,]; // Please set the sheet names you want to use.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchClear({ ranges: sheetNames.flatMap(s => ["C3:S40", "U3:U40"].map(r => `'${s}'!${r}`)) }, ss.getId());
}
```

I think that when Sheets API is used, the process cost might be able to be reduced a little. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)

#### References:

- [getRangeList(a1Notations) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangelista1notations)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchClear](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchClear)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)